# Submenu drops one line lower than it should

Tags: css, submenu

Hi guys and Happy New Year!

I am having some trouble with the CSS of the navigation menu submenu items on my WordPress website.

[image: Issue illustrated in the screenshot]

As you can see in the screenshot, the sub-submenu is displayed one line further down than it should be, making it nearly impossible for the user to use it.

The website is live on [here](https://veganopolis.online) and I'm struggling to find what is wrong with the CSS. Everything seems fine.

Can anyone help me out? What should I add/change to ensure that the 3rd level menu items appear in the correct place?

Thank you very much in advance for your help and time!

Comment: Are you able to show a small part of your code that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code solved it:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.menu>li.menu-item-has-children ul li > ul {
    top: -1px !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove top 100% from the below CSS class, then list items will be aligned properly.

```
`.menu>li.menu-item-has-children:hover ul {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    /* top: 100%; */
    z-index: 999;
}`
```